Definition of Cocategory
The definition of a category is readily available anywhere. However, finding an explicit simple definition of a cocategory is hard. I found a definition on this post, but could not understand the meaning of it.
So I have tried to define a cocategory by trying to dualize things in the definition of a category.
Definition:
A cocategory $\mathbf{C}$ consists of the following data:

A class $\mathrm{Ob}(\mathbf{C})$ of objects of $\mathbf{C}$.

For any pair $(a,b)$ of objects in $\mathbf{C}$ there exists a set $\mathrm{Hom}_\mathbf{C}(a,b)$ of morphisms from $a$ to $b$.

For any object $a$ in $\mathbf{C}$ there exists a morphism $\mathrm{id}_a \in \mathrm{Hom}_\mathbf{C}(a,a)$ known as the coidentity morphism.

For any ordered triple $(a,b,c)$ of objects in $\mathbf{C}$ there exists a cocomposition map
\begin{equation}
   \Delta_{abc}: \mathrm{Hom}_\mathbf{C}(a,c) \to \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{C}}(b,c) \times 
   \mathrm{Hom}_\mathbf{C}(a,b)
\end{equation}
satisfying the following coassociativity condition:
$\hspace{100in}$ 


Am I going in the right direction? Kindly, help me out. If this is correct. What diagram should the coidentity element satisfy?

Some considerations on dualizing the product to the coproduct. But ultimately the variables $a, b, c$ needs to be dualized to covariables too, hence the pushouts in the linked post.

Can you please help me understand in in simple terms? Or is there any source where I will get the definition of cocategory explained in detailed

Your approach is not correct. Please explain more what you don't understand about the linked post (which makes this here basically a duplicate).

Can you please help me understand why is my approach not correct?
